# Show that an algebraic extension $L/ \mathbb{F}_q$ admits no non-trivial valuations

Tags: commutative-algebra, finite-fields, valuation-theory

> Show that a field which is algebraic over a finite field has no non-trivial valuations.

Due to lulu's comment I think I should clearly specify that **I am working with an additive valuation**.

Let $\Bbb F$ be a finite field (of characteristic say $p$) and $L$ be an algebraic extension over $\Bbb F$ .

I know that valuations correspond to valuation rings and hence it suffices to show that any proper subring of $L$ fails to be a valuation ring. Intuitively it seems to attack with a non-normal argument, but can't really see it coming.

Or maybe something like defining a valuation on $L$ and then restricting it onto $\Bbb F$ and

I am aware of the following informations: For any $\alpha \in L$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha $ over $\Bbb F$ is of the form $X^{p^n}-X$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$ and also that $\Bbb F$ is never Algebraically closed.

Or maybe something like defining a valuation on $L$ and then restricting it onto $\Bbb F$ and then somehow using that $\Bbb F$ is not Algebraically closed?

Can I argue somehow with the above informations (or elsewise) to answer the question? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: @lulu Are you trying to suggest that every element is a root of unity then consider the norm $||.||$ , since $||1||=1$ thus $||ab||=||a||||b|| \implies \forall \alpha \in L, ||\alpha||=1 $ ?

Comment: Yes. The norm of any element has to be either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @lulu I should had specified before that my valuation is defined additively.

Comment: Same thing. $0=v(1)=v(a^n)=nv(a)\implies v(a)=0$.

Comment: @lulu, Oh yeah since $v : L^* \to G$ is a group homomorphism, right?

Comment: You do need to argue that we can find $n$ prime to the characteristic, but that's not difficult.

Comment: @lulu Yeah can you just write a complete answer. I really appreciate how our discussion helped me and if you give an answer I would like to accept it!

Comment: As it happens, your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410561/how-to-show-the-only-absolute-value-on-a-finite-field-is-the-trivial-one).

Comment: @lulu I find your linked question slightly different, anyway would you post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\alpha \in L^*$.  Then, since $\alpha$ is algebraic over a finite field, it must satisfy an equation of the form $x^{p^k-1}=1$.  But then $$0=v(1)=v(\alpha^{p^k-1})=(p^k-1)v(\alpha)\implies v(\alpha)=0$$

Hence the valuation is trivial.